# why signed distance field keep quality perfect when scale being larger and common picture not?

Tags: fonts, webgl, textures, glyph

Here is [example](https://mapbox.s3.amazonaws.com/kkaefer/sdf/index.html) for rendering text by signed distance field(SDF):

When the fontsize getting bigger，its quality keeps perfect.

Interpolation must be there. But why common picture getting lower quality, however SDF not?

I know sdf store distance data, but why interpolation doesnot break distance data like it does for common picture?

Comment: You have to add the code to the question. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change.

Comment: SDF also suffers what bitmap suffer,  as SDF is also bitmap, but with more vertices.